# Javascript Double moving game problome

Tags: javascript

In my game, when you die a game over screen but for some reason when you click main menu, then level one again, and move to the left or right it double moves him? Every time you click start I made it so that it resets it again just in case maybe that is why? here is the function that i think might be causing the problome?

```
          $('#yes').click(function() {

                      $("#levelOne").css('margin-top', '-1520px');
                      $("#player").css('border', 'solid 1px green')
                      $("#player").css('margin-left', '223px');
                      $('#levelComplete').hide();
                      $('#levelOne').animate({
                          'margin-top': '+=1520px'
                      }, speed);
                      handleCollisions()
          $('#startLevel1').hide(); 
      });
```

link: http://jsfiddle.net/8h7n2oca/20/
Any thing helps, thanks

Answer (score 0):

When the game resets, sounds like an event is being re-bound to your player (resulting in 2 duplicate events bound to your player)  Make sure to unbind all relevant events on gameover / be careful in rebinding.

Thanks for the fiddle, I took at a look at your code.  When you start the game, you call the function levelOne(), inside this function the following code runs:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) { /* your logic */ }
```

This code is binding an event listener on the keydown event to the document.  When you call levelOne() after the game ends, this code runs again.  Now you have two listeners bound to the document.  So when you go to move your player, the code is fired twice.

Abstracting your game set up logic to a separate function to be run once on page load as suggested by GameAlchemist sounds like a good approach to prevent duplicate bindings and optimize your code.

Comment: What do you mean by bind?